# Trying to read from a text file, store it into an an arrayList and print the stored information unto my screen. Why is my output empty?

Tags: java, arraylist

Would like to print out the stored information. How can I solve this issue?

```
public class schoolTimeTable {

    private static ArrayList<String> timesArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {


        File file = new File("C:/Users/Tommy/workspace/Prov/src/TestPaket/text.txt");
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

            String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");

            String[] times = tokens;
            for(String time: times)
            timesArray.add(time);
            System.out.println(timesArray); 



        }} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}}
```

Comment: "Printing" a ArrayList won't (normally) print the contents of the array list, but what ever ArrayList#toString wants to print, which is typically the objects hashCode

Comment: I bet an exception is thrown and since you don't print the stack trace in the catch block, you don't see anything. Never do an empty catch block.

Comment: @MadProgrammer AbstractCollection (of which ArrayList is a subclass) redefines toString() so that it prints the collection elements enclosed in square brackets. This is documented so I guess one can rely on this.

Comment: Quite wrong, MadProgrammer.  See below.

Comment: @CyrilleKa : You are right. Realised that i inputed the wrong path name. Will not underestimate the importance of stack tracing from now on! Thanks

Comment: @duffymo Hmm, nice to learn something new. I guess my problem is I'm use to relying on `List` and don't trust the implementation :P (which is clearly not the problem here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because nothing is being printed, my assumption would be that the file name is incorrect, or that Java doesn't like it.

Double-check the path, and try replacing forward slashes with (double) backslashes, like so:

```
C:\\Users\\Tommy\\workspace\\Prov\\src\\TestPaket\\text.txt
```

And, of course, as others of said, change your `catch` block to:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The slashes should make no difference (validating the path is also a good idea) - but printing the exception is defiantly a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You'll do better if you pay more attention to code format and style.  It matters a great deal to both readability and understanding.

The catch block does nothing.  You should never, ever have an empty catch block.  Always print the stack trace at minimum.

Works fine for me:

```
package cruft;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * SchoolTimeTable
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318400/trying-to-read-from-a-text-file-store-it-into-an-an-arraylist-and-print-the-sto/15318413#15318413
 * @since 3/9/13 10:02 PM
 */
public class SchoolTimeTable {

    private static List<String> timesArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("resources/timeTable.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] times = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
                for (String time : times) {
                    timesArray.add(time);
                }
                System.out.println(timesArray);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I put this timeTable.txt in a resources file in my project:

```
1
2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Here's the output I got when I ran it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" cruft.SchoolTimeTable
[1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This looks right to me.

Comment: Can't imagine why anybody would downvote this.  What on earth is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Also is to read the file?
I run your code.Is right.
The contents of the file is:

demo1,28,feb-01,true
demo2,22,dec-03,false
demo3,21,dec-03,false
demo4,25,dec-03,true

The file name：Visitor.txt
I changed a little bit of code：

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class schoolTimeTable {
    private static ArrayList<String> timesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("d:/Visitor.txt");
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
                String[] times = tokens;
                for (String time : times)
                    timesArray.add(time);
            }
            System.out.println(timesArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output：
[demo1,28,feb-01,true, demo2,22,dec-03,false, demo3,21,dec-03,false, demo4,25,dec-03,true].

In my opinion you the contents of the file format.
You compare the contents of the file format.
Hope to be able to help